# ping pong DMA in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I am using a SoC to DMA data from the programmable logic side (PL) to the processor side (PS).  My overall scheme is to allocate two separate dma buffers and ping-pong data to these buffers to the user-space application can access data without collisions.  I have successfully done this using single dma transactions in a loop (in a kthread) with each transaction either on the first or second buffer.  I was able to notify a poll() method of either the first or second buffer.

Now I would like to investigate scatter-gather and/or cyclic DMA.

```
struct scatterlist      sg[2]
struct dma_async_tx_descriptor *chan_desc;
struct dma_slave_config config;

sg_init_table(sg, ARRAY_SIZE(sg));

addr_0 = (unsigned int *)dma_alloc_coherent(NULL, dma_size, &handle_0, GFP_KERNEL);
addr_1 = (unsigned int *)dma_alloc_coherent(NULL, dma_size, &handle_1, GFP_KERNEL);

sg_dma_address(&sg[0]) = handle_0;
sg_dma_len(&sg[0]) = dma_size;
sg_dma_address(&sg[1]) = handle_1;
sg_dma_len(&sg[1]) = dma_size;

memset(&config, 0, sizeof(config));
config.direction = DMA_DEV_TO_MEM;
config.dst_addr_width = DMA_SLAVE_BUSWIDTH_4_BYTES;
config.src_maxburst = DMA_MAX_BURST_SIZE / DMA_SLAVE_BUSWIDTH_4_BYTES;
dmaengine_slave_config(dma_dev->chan, &config);
chan_desc = dmaengine_prep_slave_sg(dma_dev->chan, &sg[0], 2, DMA_DEV_TO_MEM, DMA_CTRL_ACK | DMA_PREP_INTERRUPT);

chan_desc->callback = sync_callback;
chan_desc->callback_param = dma_dev->cmp;
init_completion(dma_dev->cmp);

dmaengine_submit(chan_desc);
dma_async_issue_pending(dma_dev->chan);

dma_free_coherent(NULL, dma_size, addr_0, handle_0);
dma_free_coherent(NULL, dma_size, addr_1, handle_1);
```

This works fine for a single run through the scatterlist and then calls the call_back at sync_callback.  My thought was to chain the scatterlist in a loop but I won't get the callback.

IS THERE A WAY to have a callback for each descriptor in the scatterlist?  I wondered if I could use *dmaengine_prep_slave_cyclic* (calls callback after every transaction) but it looks to me like this is for a single buffer when reviewing [dmaengine.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dmaengine.h?v=3.19#L459).  Looking at [DMA Engine API Guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dmaengine/client.txt) it looks like there is another option *dmaengine_prep_interleaved_dma* using a *dma_interleaved_template* that sounds interesting but hard to find info about.

In the end I just want to signal the user space in some manner as to what buffer is ready.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it? I'm trying to do the same thing (similar at least), and I keep finding posts with similar questions but no answers...

Comment: I was unable to find a method using the dma api.  I opted to not use scatter-gather and just use single dma operations on different memory addresses

Comment: Too bad. I found that the driver for my DMA controller (ATMEL at_xdma) invokes a callback for every block transferred when in cyclic mode, but I don't find this behaviour documented anywhere. However, it requires me to create a (large) coherent buffer, so it is limited in the amount of data that I can buffer. An SG-based implementation would be nicer, I think.